# JavaScript: What is the best way to retrieve the selected value from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I simply want to retrieve the value of the selected option from the dropdown menu. I put together something haphazard below that was almost functioning.

What is an appropriate solution for this task?

You will see that there are four option values to select form the dropdown menu: Audi, Citroen, BMW, Tesla. I want to know which value is selected from the dropdown in order to display content on the page corresponding to the selection.

Code below:

```js
// WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO RETRIEVE THE VALUE FROM THE DROPDOWN MENU?
function pageSelected() {
if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value == 1) {
document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = "Audi";
} else if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value == 2) {
document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = "Citroen";
} else if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value == 3) {
document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = "BMW";
} else if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value == 4) {
document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = "Ford";
}
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function ddm() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="infobar">
<div id="info">
</div>

<!--dropdown option value goes here-->
<div id="optionvalue">option value</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="ddm()" class="dropbtn">&#9660;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a><option value="1" onclick="pageSelected()" >Audi</option></a>
    <a><option value="2" onclick="pageSelected()">Citroen</option></a>
    <a><option value="3" onclick="pageSelected()">BMW</option></a>
    <a><option value="4" onclick="pageSelected()">Ford</option></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value = 1)` You're doing assignment not comparison. Should be: `if (document.getElementById("myDropdown").value == 1) {`

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the element to `pageSelected` and get the value from there

```
<option value="1" onclick="pageSelected(this)" >Audi</option>

function pageSelected(option) {
    document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = option.value + ' ' + option.innerHTML;
}
```

---

```js
// WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO RETRIEVE THE VALUE FROM THE DROPDOWN MENU?
function pageSelected(option) {
document.getElementById("optionvalue").innerHTML = option.value + ' ' + option.innerHTML;
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function ddm() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<div id="infobar">
<div id="info">
</div>

<!--dropdown option value goes here-->
<div id="optionvalue">option value</div>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="ddm()" class="dropbtn">&#9660;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a><option value="1" onclick="pageSelected(this)" >Audi</option></a>
    <a><option value="2" onclick="pageSelected(this)">Citroen</option></a>
    <a><option value="3" onclick="pageSelected(this)">BMW</option></a>
    <a><option value="4" onclick="pageSelected(this)">Ford</option></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Musa for this great answer. In "pageSelected(this)" is "this" where the element is being passed to?

Comment: `this` is the current element, the element that has onlclick attribute(in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the very first Google result for "javascript get dropdown value":

```
var e = document.getElementById ("myDropdown");
var selectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are after. 
If you are wanting the value (the ID) you can simply use this:

```
$("#ID of drop").val()
```

However if you are after the text I would suggest using this:

```
$("#ID of drop option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [HTML `<select>` tag for your dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). This will work well with the browser and [you can also attach an event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to fire when the dropdown is interacted with.

```
<p>Selected: <span id="value"></span></p>

<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Audi</option>
    <option value="1">Citroen</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Tesla</option>
</select>
```

And then

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

// When the dropdown is changed,
// this function runs
dropdown.addEventListener("change", handleSelect);

// Obtain the default value
var selected = dropdown.value;
var displayValue = document.getElementById("value");

displayValue.innerText = selected;

// Event handler ran when the
// dropdown changes
function handleSelect(event) {
  var updatedValue = event.target.value;
  displayValue.innerText = updatedValue;
}
```